# Adding unique ID for each row in scala dataframe for multiple insertions

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to unique ID for each row in my scala dataframe and hence I can insert dataframe from databricks notebook into SQL DB.

```
val df2 = df1.withColumn("unique_ID",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

This works for the first ingestion into SQL DB. But when I try to ingest the new data, I get the duplicate key error "The duplicate key value is..XXXX"

How to overcome to generate unique key for every SQL ingestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding the identifier yourself by hand (which I imagine is failing because `monotonicallyIncreasingId` always starts from 0 even if that is already stored on the database you're trying to save to) you can probably add an auto-increasing identifier column to the schema of the database you're saving on. Every RDBMS has its own way to allow you to do that, [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_autoincrement.asp) shows how to do it on a selection of SQL database implementations. For example, in MySQL you would add the `AUTO_INCREMENT` qualifier to a column:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Personid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (Personid)
);
```

When saving the dataframe you would not need to specify the auto-increasing identifier (i.e. in the example above your dataframe ought to contain only `LastName`, `FirstName` and `Age~